# How can I diagnose a connection failure to my Load-balanced Service Fabric Cluster in Azure?

Tags: azure, connection, azure-service-fabric

I'm taking my first foray into Azure Service Fabric using a cluster hosted in Azure. I've successfully deployed my cluster via ARM template, which includes the cluster manager resource, VMs for hosting Service Fabric, a Load Balancer, an IP Address and several storage accounts. I've successfully configured the certificate for the management interface and I've successfully written and deployed an application to my cluster. However, when I try to connect to my API via Postman (or even via browser, e.g. Chrome) the connection invariably times out and does not get a response. I've double checked all of my settings for the Load Balancer and traffic should be getting through since I've configured my load balancing rules using the same port for the front and back ends to use the same port for my API in Service Fabric. Can anyone provide me with some tips for how to troubleshoot this situation and find out where exactly the connection problem lies ?

To clarify, I've examined the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/create-load-balancer-rule), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients)

Comment: without access to the entire environment\configuration is hard to diagnose what is the problem, might be many issues, I would recommend go step by step following one of the SF guides and check if you are not missing something

Comment: Sure, got a link? I've tried several already, which ones are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in to one of your service fabric nodes via remote desktop and calling your API directly from the VM?  I have found that if I can confirm it's working directly on a node, the issue likely lies within the LB or potentially an NSG.

Comment: Yes, I did this after my original post (still new to VMSS and Load Balancers) and found that the Service Fabric host is running the service (`netstat -an`) and it's listening, but not actually receiving what's sent (`netstat -an | ? { $_ -like '*8870*' }`). So the availability tests are actually right. Looking in my Service Fabric cluster manager, everything's green across the board. Here's what I get from `netstat`: ` TCP    0.0.0.0:8870           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    10.0.0.4:8870          168.63.129.16:52439    ESTABLISHED`

Comment: Gotcha... in that case I would probably go ahead and rule out NSG and LB as potential failure points, for now.  I am guessing your app is failing.  I mean, if you have confirmed it's listening, but appears to not be receiving directly from the host it's listening on... you could confirm this by publishing say the gettingstarted app on github and confirming it works.  If it does, gotta be your app!

Comment: Oh, at this point, it's definitely my app. I've run into this error before when my application identity (NetworkService) didn't have access to the certificates used by my application but I've fixed the permissions on the VMSS instances so that's not it.

Comment: I am curious if you have a logging mechanism built in to your app?  Have a look in to serilog... it might help you glean some information that will get you what you need.

Comment: Correction to my comment above: that actually was it. The service process was running under NetworkService account and just took some time to reboot and recognize the certificates.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out. Are you pushing in your certificates via the template when you submit the fabric deployment?  We haven't yet had an issue with the certs--it is all handled at deployment time via the template.

Comment: Yes, I am. The deployment injects the certs into my VMSS VM images just fine, seems the only issue is permissions. I can automate the permissions with a custom script extension. I'm still concerned that there was absolutely nothing in the service fabric logs to indicate that there was a problem reading the certificate though

Comment: To add further details, I'm using Kestrel for my server, very similar to this article: https://dzimchuk.net/setting-up-https-endpoints-in-asp-net-core-services-in-service-fabric/